# Number of distinct Feynman Diagrams for different orders of $\phi^4$ theory for 2 point function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory

There is 1 **distinct** Feynman diagram for zeroth order and 2 **distinct** diagrams for first order in $\phi^4$ theory for **two point function**. I want to know is there a way to predict the number of **distinct** Feynman diagrams for higher orders in $\phi^4$ theory for **two point function**.